# Angular SSR - Universal,

Tags: node.js, angular

Build myself a Angular website and for my own learning curve, wanted to implement Angular Universal. Followed the tutorial: https://angular.io/guide/universal. Want to achieve that all the html is "prerendered" for better crawling/indexing by search engines.

But it looks like it needs a service worker or nodejs hosting to get this working? Isn't it possible with a shared/apache hosting? Or are there better ways to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could consider going fully static with scully.io instead of using ssr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot serve the application with static files only. You must have a server that will render the HTML in every request.
Some of the options you can do is:

1. Use a cloud service like AWS Elastic Beanstalk
2. Launch a linux machine and serve through it (maybe with pm2, nginx)

Comment: Thank you bro, will def look into those options, these are actually nice handhelds.